# Setting currency and language values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to improve my code, but I'm not sure where to start. Everything works as I want it to; I just think it's ugly.

I'll split this into two parts:

1. I have two drop-downs that I'll explain later. In these drop-downs, I have options to set currency and language. I use a hidden form to set the current values with PHP, and extract the current value from these field. I then compare if the selected value matches the initial one.
2. Within my two drop-downs, clicking on one or the other closes the other one, and open itself if it's not open. Upon closing the drop-down, I check if I should submit the form (`reloadPage()`).

I think this should be split into separate functions, but I don't really know how to merge all of this together. I'm not asking for a full recode of my stuff, but I'd appreciate how to make this less ugly.

**Part 1**

```
$(function() {
    hasChanged = false;
    var $options = $('#options');
    var $currencycode = $options.find('#currency_code');
    var $languagecode = $options.find('#language_code');
    var $initCurrencycode = $currencycode.val();
    console.log($initCurrencycode);
    $('.monnaie').find('a').click(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if(!$this.hasClass('selected')) {
            $this.parent().siblings().find('a').removeClass('selected');
            $myCurrencycode = $this.attr('class');
            $currencycode.val($myCurrencycode);
            $this.addClass('selected');
            if($myCurrencycode == $initCurrencycode) {
                hasChanged = false;
                console.log(hasChanged);
            } else {
                hasChanged = true;
                console.log(hasChanged);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Part 2**

```
$optionsdropdown = $('#mobile-options');
$menudropdown = $('#mobile-menu');
function reloadPage() {
    if(hasChanged) {
        alert('reload now');
    } else {
        console.log('nope');
    }
}
$('.options-toggler').click( function() {
    if(!$optionsdropdown.hasClass('hide')) {
        $optionsdropdown.addClass('hide');
    } else {
        $optionsdropdown.removeClass('hide');
    }
    if(!$menudropdown.hasClass('hide')) {
        $menudropdown.addClass('hide');
    }
});
$('.menu-toggler').click( function() {
    if(!$menudropdown.hasClass('hide')) {
        $menudropdown.addClass('hide');
    } else {
        $menudropdown.removeClass('hide');
    }
    if(!$optionsdropdown.hasClass('hide')) {
        $optionsdropdown.addClass('hide');
    }
});
$('html').click(function() {
    if(!$optionsdropdown.hasClass('hide')) {
        $optionsdropdown.addClass('hide');
    }
    if(!$menudropdown.hasClass('hide')) {
        $menudropdown.addClass('hide');
        reloadPage();
    }
});
$('#mobile-menu, .menu-toggler').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$('#mobile-options, .options-toggler').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

My 2 cents:

- Use jQuery toggleClass : http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/
- Use camelCase : currencycode -> currencyCode etc.
- Use English everywhere : 'monnaie' should not be there
- Booleans are awesome

> ```
>         if($myCurrencycode == $initCurrencycode) {
>             hasChanged = false;
>             console.log(hasChanged);
>         } else {
>             hasChanged = true;
>             console.log(hasChanged);
>         }
> ```
>
> should be
>
> ```
>    hasChanged = ($myCurrencycode != $initCurrencycode)
>    console.log( hasChanged );
> ```

- Finally,

> ```
> if(!$menuDropdown.hasClass('hide')) {
>   $menuDropdown.addClass('hide');
> }
> ```
>
> can be replaced with `$menuDropdown.addClass('hide');`
>   it will not add the class multiple times.

Comment: OP isn't even using `hasChanged`, so he could also go a step further and use `console.log($myCurrencycode != $initCurrencycode);`.  Though that's starting to approach the edge between brevity and readability.

Comment: I actually wrote exactly that and then removed it.

Comment: Thank you, I've applied your suggestions to my code (I've edited my original post)

Comment: @tomdemuyt: "results indicate a significant improvement in time and lower visual effort with the underscore style" ~ http://www.cs.kent.edu/~jmaletic/papers/ICPC2010-CamelCaseUnderScoreClouds.pdf

Comment: @DaveJarvis Sure, but for JavaScript the standard is camelCase, when in Rome..

Answer (score 3):

`.addClass()` won't add a class multiple times, so this:

```
if(!$optionsDropdown.hasClass('hide')) {
    $optionsDropdown.addClass('hide');
}
```

can be rewritten as:

```
$optionsDropdown.addClass('hide');
```

But why even use a `hide` class at all ? jQuery has [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) helper functions, so you can just write:

```
$optionsDropdown.hide();
```

Comment: Because I'm applying the class in the source, I find it more semantic to hide a dropdown menu with a class than with hide(). I might be wrong, but I don't know. I will update my code to use addClass once, thanks :)